# Cannot convert BasicDBList to array (java)

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection where documents contain several arrays.  I"m retrieving those documents and storing their data into POJOs.

In some instances, I can do this:

```
BasicDBList kws = (BasicDBList)obj.get(Constants.KEYWORDS_STR);
if(!kws.isEmpty())  
    tb.setKeywords(kws.toArray(new String[0]));
```

However, I have one array that's stumping me.  I thought it contained Longs, but toArray(new Long[0]) throws java.lang.ArrayStoreException.  I figured ok, for some reason they are stored as Strings, and tried converting to an array of Strings, and still got a java.lang.ArrayStoreException.

How can I tell what class the BasicDBList thinks it has stored in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `BasicDBList extends ArrayList<Object>`, (note - generics are not used), so there's no guarantee that `kws` will contain homogeneous types within it. You should be able to change `new String[0]` to `new Object[0]` and avoid the exception.

There's no way to easily interrogate the array without some kind of statements:

```
if (instanceof ){...} 
else if (instanceof) {...}
```

Your data model should be mapped out well enough that this pattern is not required, or at least well enough that you know the finite set of what to expect.

Comment: According to my data model, it should have been Longs.  It appears that the JSON serializer converted the Longs to Integers before they got inserted into MongoDB, so they got read out as Integers.

Comment: The driver will try to fit the value into 32 bits if it can and promote it to 64 bits if it has to. Similarly it will deserialize attempting to fit it into 53 bits if it can. If it cannot it will return an instance of Long to avoid losing precision.

Answer (score 0):

By getting the iterator for the BasicDBList and looking at the objects, I found that it held Integers (which is weird, as it should be Longs, but that's the subject of another question).